# Preserve SmartObject link

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I'm using a smart object at two places (in the same file), and I need them to be linked, so that if I edit the content of one, the changes are applied on the other.

And it's working fine… until I use one of these smart objects inside another smart object. From the moment I create this third smart object, the link is broken, and the content doesn't update anymore.

One workaround is to use an external file imported as a link, but is there a way not to break the link in the first place?

**EDIT**

Screenshot of my layers to clarify:

[image: complete artwork]
The complete artwork: "hex" and "bg" are both in the main picture and in the "bg copy" smart object, but the link is broken…

[image: inside 3rd smart object]
Here's the content of the 3rd smart object (the one called "bg copy" in the previous capture).

Comment: Could you simply include both of the cloned smart objects inside the third one?

Comment: No because I apply an effect on the third on that must not be applied on one of the clones.

Comment: Can you put all of it into a group and convert that group to a smart object?

Comment: A screenshot of your layers and effects might be helpful.

Comment: @13ruce I edited my question with captures

Comment: Embedded Smart Objects have to be in the same document in order to maintain the link. Technically the contents of an Embedded Smart Object are in a separate .psb file. It's pretty much exactly as Scott was saying. What you should do is copy the contents of `bg copy` Smart Object back to the main document and make a new copy of the bg Smart Object to replace that old copy and maybe group them if you feel you need that. This wouldn't change anything visually, but the SO link would not be broken anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a little on what I said in the comments.

> In order to retain the Embedded Smart Object links, you need to keep them in the same document. Technically the contents of an Embedded Smart Object are in a separate .psb file, so that is a no-no.

What you should do is copy the contents of `bg copy` Smart Object back to the main document and make new copies of the original Smart Objects to make sure they are in sync.

So something like this:

[image]

Comment: Ok, we agree on that. Now, my problem is that if I create a new smart object from the group you named "Copy" in your example, the link between "bg" and "bg copy" and the link between "Hex" and "Hex copy" is broken.

Comment: @gregseth, do we? The whole point of this answer was that you don’t make a smart object from that group because it breaks that link. You need to keep them in yhe same document to maintain the link. — Why would you do that? Do you just want to break the link no matter what?

Answer (score 0):

Copying smart object layers, by default, makes the copy the *same reference as the original*. If you merely duplicate the smart object layer, you have 2 layers both with **the same smart object contents**. Edit one, the other will update to reflect the edits.

I don't see the problem **unless** you are using `New Smart Object Via Copy` command by mistake. *That* particular command creates a new, unlinked, smart object. So, don't use that command if you want the smart objects linked to the same contents.

Comment: And that's the case, until I create a new smart object with the copies inside: this action "breaks" the link. It's like Photoshop uses "New Smart Object Via Copy" to put the objects in the new  one. And I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: I'm not understanding.. so you have a smart object inside a smart object inside a smart object? Is there a reason you can't merely use layer grouping rather than nesting smart objects?

Comment: No, as shown in the captures I've only two levels : a smart object, and a smart object (which is a copy of the first one) inside a smart object.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand anything about those screen captures. They appear to be different configurations entirely. To me.. it looks like (and I could be wrong) you are unnecessarily creating too many smart objects and they aren't all needed. Your bottom screen shot has a clipping mask active.. the top screen shot has no clipping mask.. they are completely different. I also have *no clue* which image is even the desired appearance. Your question is unclear.

Comment: The first one is my main document. The second one is the content of the smart object selected in the first one.

Comment: I'm sorry, you should edit the question and add **a lot** more detail.

Comment: But they ARE. Do you even know that by double clicking a smart object, you can see and edit its content ?

Comment: @gregseth All I'm doing is attempting to **help you** and you want to question my ability?  You need my resume to help solve a problem you can't solve? I'm Adobe Certified.. I have used Photoshop since version 2.0.1 .....and been in the design business for more than 30 years... and I do not understand your question that is in *no way* my fault. I didn't write the question. I've asked for clarity and gotten little or none.... Sorry I'm putting *you* out by trying to help you. Ridiculous. Good luck. I honestly hope you figure it out. I'm done.